# How to cache large fie in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Currently we try to place a 3D scene on our website, but It has a large data source file about 500Mb, I don't know why I have to download it everytime when I open the site, I try to add headers such as cache-control, expires but all fails. I do some simple tests and found that chrome does cache files when they are smaller than 25Mb, and with an about 200Mb total limitation, that is say if I have 10 files(they are all about 25Mb), some of them would not be cached too. So how can I make this large file cache by chrome? Is this limitation depends on the machine or configuration?

Comment: browsers probably dont like you caching files that large. is there a way to distill the data into views of data at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It is hard to do that because they are packaged by UE4, the process of fetching data is controled by their scripts.

Comment: Conventional cache-control mechanism is definitely not on your side. You might take a chance with service worker and Cache API though. Chrome allow you to use up to <6% of user's free disk space. check [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa)

Comment: We are trying to use indexDB, thanks